# Submitted ios app binary successfully still on itunes connect status shows prepare for submission

Tags: xcode, app-store-connect, xcode6

I have successfully submitted My ios app binary to itunes connect using xcode 6. 
[image]

After that when I checked app status on itunes instead of waiting it still shows prepare for submission.
which is quite unusual.

[image]

So I thought I might have not submitted the app properly and I tried to re submit it. However I failed as it says binary is already exist.

[image]

Does any1 else has encounter this problem? Please provide appropriate solutions.

Thanks

Comment: This question is off-topic because it is about App Store functionality, not a coding issue. Please see [Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic for Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/175701)

Comment: Thanks for asking the question.  I wonder how a question directly related to a topic with it's own tag can be off topic. +1

Comment: Even i am facing the same issue. I submitted the binary successfully and it passed all validations, but still didn't find the build with the expected build number in iTunes Connect. Quite frustrating..

Comment: Xcode 6.2 organizer didn't work as expected for me, but tried it with application loader 3.1, then it worked.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The process has changed slightly. After you upload a build you now have to goto iTunes Connect and select the build. You then have to submit the app for review.

Open your App Details page where you type in the metadata about the app. There is a section for builds. You need to select one.

[image]

Once you have selected a build there will be a button at the top of the screen that allows you to submit the app for review.

If you are still stuck, the documentation has been updated with the new workflow. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/SubmittingTheApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH33-SW4

Comment: Thankx man but When I click on submit for review it says You must submit your builds using Xcode 5.1.1 or later despite the fact I have used xcode 6

Answer (score 2):

In itunes Account again you have to select your uploaded build, and submit your app to appstore. recently this process changed.

if you scroll iTunesConnectMyapps screen in middle you find **Build** section like below
[image]

here select your build and  **submit for review** you can find this button at top. here adding screen shot.[image]

Comment: Thankx man but When I click on submit for review it says You must submit your builds using Xcode 5.1.1 or later despite the fact I have used xcode 6